# multiprocess.process overwriting files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm a beginner to the `multiprocess` library.

I'm trying to chunk a list of ids, for example: `[12, 34, 56, 78, 910, 1112]` into even size chunks, `[[12, 34, 56], [78, 910, 1112]]` to split the jobs and make several API requests concurrently.

The code I have is here:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def chunks(l, n):
    # split a list into evenly sized chunks
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]


def run_golang(job_id, data_slice):
    '''
       Takes a string of ids, feeds it into a golang API script
       and returns a csv file of output data
    '''

    str_slice = ','.join(str(i) for i in data_slice)
    p = subprocess.Popen('./golang --ids={}'.format(str_slice)
                                            , shell=True
                                            , stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                                            , stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
   ...


def dispatch_jobs(data, job_number):
    total = len(data)
    chunk_size = total / job_number
    slice = chunks(data, int(chunk_size))
    jobs = []

    for i, s in enumerate(slice):
        j = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_golang, args=(i, s))
        jobs.append(j)
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [12, 34, 56, 78, 910, 1112]
    dispatch_jobs(data, 2)
```

The problem (I think) is that since the processes are created at the same time, the .csv file the golang script creates is overwriting each other (`filename_T18:14:45.csv`). So at the end of the python script execution, I'm left with 1 file instead of 2 in this example.

If there is a way to create processes sequentially instead of simultaneously (with a second or two delay), that may fix my problem but I haven't been able to SO sleuth my way to an answer.

Thanks to any responses!

Comment: Have you tried starting a job immediately after creation and doing `time.sleep(N)` so that there's an `N` seconds delay between those? Alternatively, if you have access to that golang script (which I assume you do), you can change it to accept another argument acting as a unique identifier for files created simultaneously - just add `job_id` at the end of the filename or something, and it should work fine.

Comment: @AlexF Maybe its a bit more complicated that this, but do you mean just adding a `time.sleep(N)` at the top of my `run_golang` function?  I tried that and it didn't seem to work.
I could modify the golang script but unfortunately is already compiled. I don't have the raw code but I could probably get it and I think thats a good idea actually.

Comment: @AlexF I just tried it again, but this time placing the sleep function after my `for j in jobs:` part of the and it seemed to have worked! Thanks for the help!